# How do I specify a type for a function parameter that optionally includes a given method?

Tags: typescript-generics

### Updated Question

I want to define a function named `bsearch()` to do binary searches against arrays of arbitrary object types.  When I invoke the function, I want it to check whether or not the `Type` of the array contains a `compare()` method and use it, if it does.  If it does not, I want it to fall back to using `<` and `===` (so it will work with strings and numbers).

What should the function declaration look like?  (I don't need an actual implementation, just the syntax for a type-safe solution.)

Or maybe I'm going about this all wrong?  How can I create a function that uses a method built into a parameter type if it exists, or use some other function when it doesn't?

### Original Question

*This is the original question, but I've replaced it with the above as it seems this wasn't getting my point across.*

I want to define a function named `bsearch()` to do binary searches against arrays of arbitrary object types.  So I'd like to do something like this:

```js
type Comparator = <Type>(a: Type, b: Type) => -1 | 0 | 1;

static bsearch<Type extends { compare?: Comparator }>(
    ary: Type[],
    value: Type
  ): number { ... }
```

My goal is to specify that `Type` must extend a type that may or may not include the `compare` method.  In my function, I will check whether the `compare` method exists on the `value` parameter and call if it does, or use a generic function (that uses `<` and `===`) if it does not.

The definition of `bsearch()` does not produce any warnings or errors, but attempts to invoke it from my unit test does:

```js
class Person {
    name: string;
    length: number;
    compare: Comparator<Person>;   // What goes here?
}

describe('Utils tests', () => {
    const arrayOfInt = [10, 20, 30, 40];
    const arrayOfStr = ['Alfred', 'Bob', 'Chuck'];
    const arrayOfPersons: Person = [
        {name:'Barney',length:2},
        {name:'Fred',length:6}
        {name:'Wilma',length:12},
    ];

    it('can find integer in an array of integers', () => {
        let search_for = 30;
        let result = Utils.bsearch(arrayOfInt, search_for)
        expect(result).to.be.equal(2);
    });

    it('can find string in an array of strings', () => {
        let search_for = 'Bob';
        let result = Utils.bsearch(arrayOfStr, search_for)
        expect(result).to.be.equal(1);
    });

    it('can find Person in an array of Persons', () => {
        // This one uses Person.compare() to do the search.
        // The previous two tests used the fallback technique.
        let search_for = {name:'Fred',length:6};
        let result = Utils.bsearch(arrayOfPersons, search_for)
        expect(result).to.be.equal(1);
    });
});
```

The error message is:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ compare?: Comparator | undefined; }[]'.   Type 'number' has no properties in common with type '{ compare?: Comparator | undefined; }'.`

I would appreciate pointers to other techniques if there is a better way to accomplish this (I'm still a TypeScript newbie).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do -- maybe including the `bsearch` code would help -- but the unit test TypeError seems correct to me. Your test isn't utilizing arbitrary objects like you mentioned.

Comment: My first sentence summarizes it:  I want to be able to do a binary search against arbitrary types.  Therefore, I need to check whether said type contains a `compare()` method.  If it does, then I'll use it.  If it doesn't, I'll use `<` and `===` as a fallback.  Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: For Typescript questions, you might want to consider linking to a Typescript playground. It becomes a lot faster for answerers to run your code :) Edit: your code also looks incomplete and I can spot multiple other type errors than the one you mentioned. You have the best chance of a meaningful answer if you can give a bit more context.

Comment: I updated the question.  I left the old question in there and tried to focus the revision to just the core question, as it seems I wasn't clear in my original question.

Comment: `Type extends { compare?: Comparator }` imply the input is an object. If you also what to support Basic types (e.g. `number` in your original question), it also need to accept any `T extends ({ compare?: Comparator<T> } | any)`.

Comment: @ChengDicky it it accepts `any` it might as well not be typed at all, `{ compare?: Comparator<T> } | any` is the same as `any`.

Comment: @tymzap I think what exactly he want is actually `any`, i.e. `the unknown element type of the input array`. I have read your answer and it is not accepting `boolean` and any other custom types like `unions of object and number` as element type. The different of just an `any` and `{ compare?: Comparator<T> } | any` is that the second one can work as a remark and help the IDE for some auto completion.

Comment: @tymzap Okay I have read the question again, it is fine as he just want `strings and numbers`.

Comment: That did it.  I have other issues to figure out now (like a type-safe way of determining whether the `compare` method exists on `Type`), but this got me past the declaration issue.  If you'll type it up as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generic is:

```
Type extends { compare?: Comparator }
```

Which means that `Type` must fulfill `{ compare?: Comparator }` type. While passing object value, for example `{ name: 'Barney', length: 2, comparator: /* snip */}`, is obviously correct, it's not the case for primitives like `10` and `Bob`. You need to include information about primitive types in the generic, for example:

```
Type extends ({ compare?: Comparator }) | number | string
```

Also, you'd probably want to enrich a bit the object typing:

```
{[key: string]: unknown, compare?: () => void } | number | string
```

Because, based on your description, you'd also want to accept also objects that do not have `compare` function in their type signature at all. If it does sound strange, I recommend reading about [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: Thanks!  I like using `number|string` better than `any`.  I don't immediately understand your last code block regarding the index field, but I'll check out your link. :)

Comment: Basically TypeScript won't allow objects without (at least optional) `compare` key in their type if you don't include this last part.